# Shiny R - reactivity not working with conditional panel

Tags: r, shiny

Problem :

In my app I have two tabs in the side panel 
Stats and Charts -
In stats I want to show the data frame and some descriptive stats (which works fine) based on the  Data thats is being selected in main panel (select input which selects the Data) and selectGroupinput( which selects the columns of the selected data) ,

in Charts I have a drop down of the columns of the selected Data and want to show bar charts for them .

Now this works smoothly when I dont put a conditional panel for selectgroupinput to be shown only in the Stat Tab and Drop down selectinput only in the Chart tab ( in the sense that the columns automatically gets updated when selecting a Data .

**Now when I put conditional panel around that ,it works smooth for the Stat tab but in Charts tab the the Columns does not function properly on changing the data set .**

I have to click the Stat tab and again click back to Charts tab to make the actual columns of the data appear in the drop down -in short the reactivity of the Data set and Column drop down is not functioning as it should be .

I have a reproducible code sample here :

https://gist.github.com/creepystranger/9168c1430c7d468fc5fb

code :
server.r

```
ibrary(shiny)
#library(RODBC)
library(ggplot2)
#library(shinyjs)
#stat_helper_function to be used in rendering stat table 

summary <- function(x) {
  funs <- c(mean, median, sd, mad, IQR,max,min)
  lapply(funs, function(f) f(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}

make_stat <- function(data){
  numeric_columns <- sapply(data,is.numeric)
  stat_table <- sapply(data[,numeric_columns],summary)
  rows <- c("Mean","Median","SD","MAD","IQR","Max","Min")
  df <- data.frame(stat_table,row.names = rows)
}
#sample prototypeof Data
data_sets <- c("iris","diamonds")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Dataset",label = "choose a dataset",as.list(data_sets))

  })

  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({

    if(is.null(input$Dataset))
      return()


    dat <<- get(input$Dataset) # make it globally accessable _saves the pain of multiple load of the data  
    colnames <- names(dat)


   checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)
    })

  output$plot_control <- renderUI({

    if(is.null(input$Dataset))
      return()
    dat #<- get(input$Dataset)
    numeric_columns <- sapply(dat,is.numeric)
    num_dat <- dat[,numeric_columns]
    colnames <- names(num_dat)

    selectInput("selectize","For the X axis and Y axis",choices=colnames)

   }) 

  output$histo_gram <- renderPlot({

    if(is.null(input$Dataset))
      return()
    #z<- matrix(num_dat,ncol = ncol(num_dat)) 
    numeric_columns <- sapply(dat,is.numeric)
    num_dat <- dat[,numeric_columns]

    num_dat

    if (is.null(input$selectize) || !(input$selectize %in% names(num_dat)))
      return()

    z <- num_dat[,input$selectize]
   # bw <- diff(range(z)) / (2 * IQR(z) / length(z)^(1/3))

    qplot(z,geom ="histogram")

  }) 



  output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({

    if(is.null(input$Dataset))
      return()


    #dat <- get(input$Dataset)
     dat

    if (is.null(input$columns) || !(input$columns %in% names(dat)))
      return()

    # Keep the selected columns
    dat <- dat[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]
    dat},  options=list(lengthMenu = c(5, 8, 10), pageLength = 5)
  ) 

  output$stat_table <- renderTable({

    dat #<- get(input$Dataset)
    num_dat <- dat[,input$columns,drop=FALSE]
    make_stat(num_dat)
      }

  )
  })
```

ui.r

```
# This is the user-interface definition of a Shiny web application.
# You can find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
# 
# http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/
#

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyUI (pageWithSidebar( 


headerPanel("Creepy-Stats"),
sidebarPanel(

      uiOutput("choose_dataset"),
      br(),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition ="input.conditionedPanels == 'Stats'",uiOutput("choose_columns")),
        conditionalPanel(condition ="input.conditionedPanels == 'Charts'" ,uiOutput("plot_control")), width = 2
#     
# uiOutput("choose_columns"),uiOutput("plot_control"),width = 2

  ),


  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Stats", 


        div (class='row',
             div(dataTableOutput("mytable1"),class="span10"),

             div(tableOutput("stat_table"),class="span5")

        ),id = "conditionedPanels"
      )


      ,

      tabPanel("Charts",

        div(class='row', 
            div(plotOutput("histo_gram"),class="span10"))       
               ),id = "conditionedPanels"

    ),width = 10
  )
))
```